# R-graphics lines look messy

Tags: r, graphics, formatting, presentation

I have a problem with my graph in R I can not find a solution anywhere. I want to have completly nice straight lines but they have small little steps I don't want to have. Actually it seems like the code is not the problem, because when I just copy other online codes  I still have the small steps whereas the online graphic didn't have.
Code is:

```
ggplot(ToM_Bed, aes(x = Beding_Forecast, y = M, color = Bedingung2, group=Bedingung2)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=M+SE, ymin=M-SE, width=.05)) +
  geom_line(size=1.2, linetype = "solid") +
  geom_point(size=1.5) +
  scale_colour_manual("Bedingung", values=c("black", "grey")) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[Graph with messy lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEeXL.png)

Hope you can help me!

Comment: How are you saving your graphs? Saving figures with `ggsave()`, which lets you specify size and dpi, creates high quality image files, while using the export button in rstudio tends to create low quality image files the one you have.